# React Admin custom route to a Show view

Tags: react-admin

I have an application with more than one show view for a resource. This is because there are different "views" on our complex "user" resource.

I have tried to add the path

```
<CustomRoutes>
    <Route path="/customUserView/:id/show" element={(props) => <CustomShow id={props.match.params.id} resource={'user'}/>} />
</CustomRoutes>
```

My `CustomShow` view works perfectly when part of the react admin routes (placed as a `show={CustomShow}` in a regular resource component, but I can't seem to get it to work outside, in a CustomView.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building your CustomShow component based on the standard Show component,
then it requires passing some of the parameters to it (for example, record) via [ShowContext](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/controller/show/ShowContext.tsx).
An implementation based on the RecordContextProvider component may be suitable for you, there is an example here: "[SimpleShowLayout - Displays Fields In A Stack](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ShowTutorial.html)".